# Which way to read a cell from Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have found two ways those were being used by people if we want to read or write to a cell in an excel.

Declaration:

```
Excel.Application ExcelApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook srcWorkBook = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test.xls");
Excel.Worksheet srcWorkSheet = srcWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
Excel.Range srcRange = srcWorkSheet.UsedRange;
```

Usage 1:

```
srcWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].value2 = "foo bar";
```

Usage 2:

```
srcRange.Cells[2, 2].Value2 = "foo bar";
```

Which one is the best way to use ? or it's all fine in .NET ?

Comment: The best option would be to avoid `Interop` libraries at all, and use instead something like [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus) that are completely implemented inside .NET.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus How about NPOI Project?

Comment: I've never used it, but from the GitHub page it seems interesting too. And it allows to handle also docx files, not only xlsx. If you have time, try both and compare them.

Comment: @MassimilianoKraus Thanks! I just downloaded the EPPlus, and used it. It's pretty faster than NPOI and it used much lesser memory. And it's easy to use.

Answer (score 5):

The two ways are **very** different.

```
srcWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].value2 = "foo bar";
```

- The 1. usage refers to the `A1` cell of the first worksheet.
- [MSDN Worksheets.Cells property Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-cells-property-excel)

---

```
srcRange.Cells[2, 2].Value2 = "foo bar";
```

- The 2. usage takes the cell on the 2. row, 2. column of the `UsedRange`. If the `UsedRange` in Excel is `B2:D5`, it would put value at `C3`:

[image]

- [MSDN Worksheets.Range Property Excel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-range-property-excel)

---

- Having a variable named `Range` as the `Range` class is really **not** a great idea. The same goes for `WorkSheet` and `WorkBook`.

Comment: thanks for the advice. That's just an variable name for example there.

Comment: @Jarkid - You are welcome. Concerning the variables - the point is that I did not understand it correctly the first time, thus I have assumed that other people would have problems as well understanding it.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the names of variables for not letting people misunderstand it.

Answer (score 1):

Either option will work, but they get messy as soon as you have to modify the layout of the worksheet.

If it's an option, I like to add named ranges. This works particularly well if you're using a template where you can modify the "starting" state of the workbook.

Let's say you have a series of columns, and one of them contains the "foo" value. You can add a name like "fooColumn" to the entire column or the top cell in the column.

Then you can get the column number using

```
worksheet.Range("fooColumn").Column
```

That protects you from having to manually edit column or row numbers all over the place if you move elements around on your worksheet.

---

And to second what others have said, use EPPlus instead of Interop. You can still use named ranges. But EPPlus is good and Interop can bring all sorts of pain when COM objects aren't released. Interop automates an application that manipulates the file. EPPlus just works with the file.